# Can Hadoop Yarn run a grid?

Tags: hadoop, grid, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

Can a Hadoop Yarn instance manage nodes from different places on Earth, networks? Can it manage nodes that use different platforms?

Every note about Yarn I found tells that Yarn manages clusters, but if the app I deploy is written in Java then it should probably work on the nodes regardless of the nodes' hardware.
Similarly, Yarn seems general enough to support more than just a LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YARN is not platform aware. It is also not aware about how application processes on different hosts communicate with each other to perform the work. 
In the same time for YARN application master should be run as a command line - and thereof any node on the cluster with enough resources should be able to run it. 
If not every platform is capable to run specific app master- then YARN should be aware on it. Today it can not, but I can imegine platform to be special kind of resource - and then YARN will select appropriate node 
Regarding LAN if you have application master which knows how to manage job over several LAN - it is should be fine with YARN.